# How can you avoid races in overriding go's default signal handlers?

Tags: linux, go, signals, coroutine

**tl;dr** if a signal can be handled by the go runtime at any time, how can we safely use `signal.Ignore` to ignore SIGINT in a way that isnt a race between when the default signal handler is installed, and when our instruction inside `main()` runs

The [go docs](https://golang.org/pkg/os/signal/) for *pkg/signal* states this about the default behavior of signals

> A SIGHUP, SIGINT, or SIGTERM signal causes the program to exit.

So, write a golang binary that spins the CPU, hit ctrl+c to send SIGINT, and the program will exit.

Now, say you want to overwrite that behavior. One way to do it would be to ignore the signal with `signal.Ignore(syscall.SIGINT)`

But now consider the following

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os/signal"
    "syscall"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Looping, SIGINT will have default behavior")
    for start := time.Now(); time.Now().Before(start.Add(time.Second * 5)); {

    }
    signal.Ignore(syscall.SIGINT)
    fmt.Println("OK")

    for start := time.Now(); time.Now().Before(start.Add(time.Second * 5)); {

    }
}
```

Here we have a simple golang binary that loops for 5 seconds. It's a busy loop so we know we do not participate in co-operative multitasking by yielding time on the OS thread. Then it registers to ignore SIGINT.

If you try this you will notice that if you enter ctrl+c during the first 5 seconds, the program will exit. This seems to make sense - we are getting the default golang runtime signal handling behavior because we have not yet overridden it with our call to `signal.Ignore`.

Now maybe we could solve this problem by moving the `signal.Ignore` to be the first thing in main(), however what this program proves is that the go runtime provides no guarantees that the default signal handler won't run before your synchronous code in main() is finished executing.

Even if you move it, we seem to be in a race between

1. The point at which the go runtime registers its default signal handlers, and
2. The earliest point at which our code can run (the first (or second if you need to make a channel) instruction in main)

I can't find documentation on this. What guarantees does the go runtime provide to make me feel absolutely sure a signal cannot arrive between stages 1 and 2?

Comment: Technically, that's not a race. The problem applies to any language with a runtime that installs default signal handlers. Even before that, by the time the runtime installs its own handlers, there's the default behavior for that signal. You can only handle (or ignore) signals after you specify that you want to handle (or ignore) them. Signals can arrive at any stage, there are no guarantees.

Comment: I disagree - there are methods to prevent this and provide those guarantees. It could, as I had hoped, say "We will not install the default signal handlers until after main() yields its P to another co-routine" or even provide a compile time flag, or type annotation to provide in-binary metadata, that would allow the runtime to make smarter decisions.

If there is nothing like this, then it would make it impossible to write predictable code that is not dependent on timing, and that is what a race is.

Comment: I believe on Linux specifically, absent any runtime guarantees, you could work-around the race by setting SIG_BLOCK after the fork and before the exec. Go docs specifically say they honor most signal masks, maybe to handle this issue. I am holding out for runtime guarantees though because I cannot control the caller
https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Process-Signal-Mask.html

Comment: You call `Ignore` after part of `main` runs; this seems to defeat your purpose. If you want to make sure it's called as soon as possible, call it first thing in `main`, or in a package `init` function (which runs before `main` is called).

Comment: The "problem" you constructed is not a real one. 1. As Burak correctly mentioned there _are_ no race and especially no undefined behaviour. 2. You can move signal.Ignore to before main starts easily as Adrian explained. 3. That are all options you have from inside a running Go application and this is good enough for almost all use cases (especially as the behaviour is not racy or undefined given that the default behaviour of the runtime for SIGINT is the default one).

Comment: 4. If for any reasons you didn't explain you must execute a binary with a nonstandard signal mask: Just do so. But for obvious reasons this cannot be done from the _inside_ of a program. 5. To answer your question "What guarantees does the go runtime provide to make me feel absolutely sure a signal cannot arrive between stages 1 and 2?" Absolutely none; like any other program written in any other programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: catch early, e.g., right at the top of `main`.

---

As the comments said, this doesn't seem to be a good way to describe this as a problem, as it's quite generic across all programming languages: if you haven't set a signal handler for `syscall.SIGINT`, you'll get killed by default on `SIGINT`, and once you have, you won't.  That's true, but *any* program can be killed during its startup, before it has a chance to start catching signals.  It's true regardless of programming language.  It affects C and C++ programs just as much as it affects Go programs.

In general, then, all you need to do to catch-or-discard `SIGINT` signals *reliably and as race-free as possible* is to use `signal.Notify(ch, os.Interrupt)` very early, near the top of your `main`, where `ch` is a channel you make for this.<sup>1</sup>  You can then write your own race-free code to deal with this via goroutines and channels:

- Have your own goroutine read the channel to see if/when a signal is delivered.
- Have it read another channel, or some shared memory area using your own mutex management, to see how to handle the signal if and when one is delivered.
- When a signal is delivered, if you should exit, call `os.Exit` (or—probably better—use `os.Reset` on `syscall.SIGINT` and then deliver yourself a `syscall.SIGINT` to generate the right OS-level exit status, "killed by signal 1"<sup>2</sup>).  If the signal should be ignored, simply drop the channel notification.

Somewhat related: there was a pretty recent fix for `syscall.SIGPIPE` handling.  In particular, calling `signal.Ignore(syscall.SIGPIPE)` should ignore `SIGPIPE`, but didn't.  [This seems to be fixed in Go 1.14.](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/32386)

---

<sup>1</sup>As the package documentation notes, deliberately catching a signal will bypass any "pre-ignored" state from `nohup` or `trap "" 1 2 15` in the shell.  If you wish to check for this, use the `signal.Ignored` function.

<sup>2</sup>If `signal_unix.go` exported the `dieFromSignal` function, you might be able to use that directly, but it doesn't.  It would be nice to have an OS-agnostic wrapper to at least attempt this kind of suicide cleanly.  This could even use `sigprocmask` at the OS level to make the suicide as race-free as possible.

Comment: Thank you @Torek this is a well thought out answer. I actually had not realized that linux had default behaviors for SIGINT and assumed most useful program and runtime simply installed them.

That said after reflecting on this further I do think there is a way to have no race, and it is to install a SIG_BLOCK mask on the child before execve which will effectively prevent it from being delivered until registered. Go docs say they support not overriding this.

That of course requires you to control the caller which may be hard, but it is something.

Comment: @Ben: yes: in theory, a program that does the `execve` system call could use `sigprocmask` to block signals during the exec, and rely on the program being started to unblock those same signals. But no *existing* programs do this, so no *shells* do this, so no programs that *aren't* shells that use `exeve` do this, so no new programs can be written that do this, which means no existing programs can be modified to do this, which means no shells will do this, which means no new programs do this, which ... well, chicken-and-egg problem here.